# lock() does not guaranty exclusive access

Tags: c#, windows-services, webservice-client, asynccallback

I am writing (my first) a web service in c#.  It is a middleware bridging our flagship product and a vendor's system, a web service. Administrative work is done using typical web service request/response.  One such administrative task is to register for callbacks on certain events.  My issue relates to correctly handling these inbound callback events - they are arriving on random managed threads:

```
5:27:16 PM: <- newEventResponse returned on managed thread id 9  
5:27:16 PM: -> notifyUpdated         received on managed thread id 9  
5:27:16 PM: <- notifyUpdatedResponse returned on managed thread id 9  
5:27:16 PM: -> notifyUpdated         received on managed thread id 9  
5:27:16 PM: <- notifyUpdatedResponse returned on managed thread id 9  
5:27:16 PM: -> notifyUpdated         received on managed thread id 9  
5:27:16 PM: <- notifyUpdatedResponse returned on managed thread id 9  
5:27:16 PM: -> newEvent         received on managed thread id 9  
5:27:19 PM: <- newEventResponse returned on managed thread id 9  
5:27:19 PM: -> newEvent         received on managed thread id 10  
5:27:19 PM: <- newEventResponse returned on managed thread id 10  
5:27:19 PM: -> notifyUpdated         received on managed thread id 9  
5:27:19 PM: <- notifyUpdatedResponse returned on managed thread id 9  
5:27:19 PM: -> notifyUpdated         received on managed thread id 10  
5:27:19 PM: <- notifyUpdatedResponse returned on managed thread id 10  
5:27:20 PM: -> newEvent         received on managed thread id 9  
5:27:20 PM: -> newEvent         received on managed thread id 5  **(Doh!)**
```

I am using lock() to force the inbound events to run through my handler in (what I thought was) an orderly manner, but testers have complained about a sudden lack of events making their way to the user interface, leading to my logging (above).

```
public static Object Mutex = new Object();

class DsrCallbackInterfaceImpl : DsrCallbackInterface
{
    public notifyUpdatedResponse notifyUpdated(notifyUpdated dsrUpdate)
    {
        lock (Lifecycle.Mutex)
        {
            try
            {
                Lifecycle.AppendLog(string.Format("-> notifyUpdated         received on managed thread id {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
                if (!Lifecycle.ShuttingDown)
                {
                    if (Lifecycle.UpdateVisibleDoorList != null)
                        Lifecycle.UpdateVisibleDoorList(dsrUpdate); 
                    DsrInteractions.DigestDoorUpdate(dsrUpdate);        
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Lifecycle.ShowException(ex, "handling notifyUpdated: " + dsrUpdate.ToString());
            }
            Lifecycle.AppendLog(string.Format("<- notifyUpdatedResponse returned on managed thread id {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
        }
        return new notifyUpdatedResponse();
    }

    public newEventResponse newEvent(newEvent dsrEvent)
    {
        lock (Lifecycle.Mutex)
        {
            try
            {
                Lifecycle.AppendLog(string.Format("-> newEvent         received on managed thread id {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
                if (!Lifecycle.ShuttingDown)
                {
                    if (Lifecycle.AddEventToVisibleLog != null)
                        Lifecycle.AddEventToVisibleLog(dsrEvent);
                    DsrInteractions.DigestEvent(dsrEvent);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Lifecycle.ShowException(ex, "handling newEvent: " + dsrEvent.ToString());
            }
            Lifecycle.AppendLog(string.Format("<- newEventResponse returned on managed thread id {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
        }
        return new newEventResponse(); ;
    }
}
```

I want to understand what I am doing wrong, specifically what I can do to limit the threads to one at a time as I believed lock() would do.

Comment: Why is your `return` statement outside of the `lock` statement?

Comment: This article is great regarding locks, even though the topic is singletons. http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx

Comment: @QualityCatalyst No reason - could this be part of the issue?

Comment: Maybe. It's outside of your lock statement and it's not clear how long it takes to create those newly created objects. Especially if the construction of those takes long time the chances increase for your described issue.

Comment: Is there a reason `Mutex` is public and mutable? If something changes it, that could explain what you are seeing.

Comment: @mikez - I will touch up the Mutex declaration

Comment: @QualityCatalyst - Placing the Return inside the lock() block made a world of difference - thanks!